# Building a single wrapper script that works for multiple executables

Tags: bash

So I have a gem that has two executables say, `run` and `run_nohup`. I have created an executable file where I add all the environment stuff required to execute the `run` and have added this on the path.

Example:

```
env variable1=value variable2=value /opt/my_gem/bin/run "$@"
```

Now my question is, is there another way to do the same for `run_nohup` without duplicating this work? I ask this because, am installing all of this with chef and it would require me to create more templates, basically duplicating the old template except for the last part where I call `run_nohup`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$0` is the name used to invoke the current program; thus, you can look at it to determine how you were called, or manipulate it (in the below case, stripping the directory name and using only the filename):

```
#!/bin/sh
exec env variable1=value variable2=value /opt/my_gem/bin/"${0##*/}" "$@"
```

You can take this single executable, save it in two files named `run` and `run_nohup` (which can be hardlinked together, if you like), and it'll call the appropriate tool from `/opt/my_gem/bin` for the name it's invoked with.

---

Aside: It would be slightly more efficient (save a few microseconds) to have the shell export the environment updates rather than calling through `env`:

```
#!/bin/sh
variable1=value variable2=value exec /opt/my_gem/bin/"${0##*/}" "$@"
```

Comment: This is what I was asking. Sorry if my question by worded incorrectly. Could you explain `${0##*/}`?

Comment: That's a parameter expansion. See BashFAQ #100: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100

Comment: BTW, I added the `exec` here as a performance enhancement -- it makes the shell replace itself with the `env` command (which in turn uses the `exec()` call to replace itself with the Ruby interpreter), rather than launching `env` (and thus your Ruby script) as a subprocess of the shell. There are actually more advantages than just performance -- doing this way also means that the PID that someone calling this script gets back can be used to signal your Ruby script, if they run it in the background and refer to `$!`, rather than having signals go to the parent shell instead.